# I've made a function to "eat" and remove other sprites, but it doesn't work and causes them to continue moving around after it has been removed

Tags: python, pygame

I've made it so if the entities collide with each other it will cause one of them to be eaten and should remove them but it doesn't and just causes a  what I'm calling a ghost which the main predator will still follow(which it shouldn't) and it will eat the carrot which it also shouldn't do).

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(predator)
all_sprites.add(prey)
all_sprites.add(carrot)


carrot_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
carrot_group.add(carrot)

Wolf_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
Wolf_group.add(predator)

Rabbit_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
Rabbit_group.add(prey)

#start of program
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    carrots = carrot_group.sprites()
    preys=Rabbit_group.sprites()
    predators=Wolf_group.sprites()


    movementx, movementy = Track(predator.x, prey.x, predator.y, prey.y)#how the predators move
    predator.move(movementx, movementy)

    

    
    if len(carrots) > 0:
        movementx, movementy = Track(prey.x, carrots[0].x, prey.y, carrots[0].y)#how the prey move
        prey.move(movementx, movementy)

    screen.fill((0,128,0))#background
    all_sprites.draw(screen)#makes the sprites
    pygame.display.update()#updates screen
    timmer=timmer+1

    for carrot in carrots:#removes the carrots if they contact a rabbit
        if prey.is_collided_with(carrot):
            print('works')
            carrot.kill()

    for prey in preys:
        if predator.is_collided_with(prey):
            print("works 2")
            prey.kill()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

the Python shell prints it out as "works 2" and then "works" it shouldn't do this as the prey should be eaten first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the variables `predator` and `prey` in the main application loop. Use the content of the *Groups* `Wolf_group` and `Rabbit_group`. Actually you don't need the variables `carrot`, `prey` and `predator`:

```py
carrot_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
carrot_group.add(Carrot())

Wolf_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
Wolf_group.add(Predator())

Rabbit_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
Rabbit_group.add(Prey())

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(carrot_group)
all_sprites.add(Wolf_group)
all_sprites.add(Rabbit_group)

#start of program
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    carrots = carrot_group.sprites()
    preys = Rabbit_group.sprites()
    predators = Wolf_group.sprites()

    if len(preys) > 0:
        for wolf in Wolf_group:
            movementx, movementy = Track(wolf.x, preys[0].x, wolf.y, preys[0].y)#how the predators move
            wolf.move(movementx, movementy)
    
    if len(carrots) > 0:
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            movementx, movementy = Track(rabbit.x, carrots[0].x, rabbit.y, carrots[0].y)#how the prey move
            rabbit.move(movementx, movementy)

    screen.fill((0,128,0))#background
    all_sprites.draw(screen)#makes the sprites
    pygame.display.update()#updates screen
    timmer=timmer+1

    for carrot in carrots:#removes the carrots if they contact a rabbit
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            if rabbit.is_collided_with(carrot):
                print('works')
                carrot.kill()

    for wolf in Wolf_group:
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            if rabbit.is_collided_with(wolf):
                print("works 2")
                rabbit.kill()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: ah ok I didn't get what you meant in the previous post which is why I made this question post, should've asked you to elaborate sorry about that